# Carousel with Auto hidding thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi Im doing some project with Bootstrap Carousel and I already made some carousel this is what my project look like [My Carousel](http://jsfiddle.net/dranir45/j7kpLb8s/15/)

my problem is I want to put my thumbnail inside of a this panel or something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dranir45/v58eozu1/3/)

this is the source code what i want to do

```js
$(function(){
 $(document).on('click','.slider-arrow.show',function(){
     $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          right: "+=300"
    }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
    $(this).html('&laquo;').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    });
 
 $(document).on('click','.slider-arrow.hide',function(){
     $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          right: "-=300"
    }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
    $(this).html('&raquo;').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden
}
.panel {
 width:300px;
 float:right;
 height:550px;
 background:#d9dada;
 position:relative;
 right:-300px;

}
.slider-arrow {
 padding:5px;
 width:10px;
 background:#d9dada;
 font:400 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#000;
 text-decoration:none;
 position:relative;
 right:-300px;
    float: right
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
      </div>
      
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slider-arrow show">&raquo;</a>
```

please can anyone help me!!

Comment: I don't see where do you call the carousel plugin from your code. I see only code of the panel. P.S. Add the jquery link to the snippet.

Comment: the carousel is on the first jsfiddle [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/dranir45/j7kpLb8s/15/)

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/zu7jq6yk/. It's long explanation so I can not list everything I did. Just read the code and you will understand.

Comment: thank you it helps me a lot but when its on the final slide it become blank

Comment: What about the console? Any errors? I think it because the iframe of the video.. Am I right?

Comment: i already finish it its because of the i frame thank you.
by the way i have another problem I want my youtube video to be pause or stop when carousel change/slide can you help me with the script tnx

Comment: Read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688919/play-youtube-video-in-flexslider-slide-and-pause-slideshow

Comment: thank you for the recommendation but the fact that i cant understand it hahaha im just new in jscripting so i cant really understand it

Comment: OK. Maybe you should try to understand it. If you can't you need to go backward and learn the basic of YouTube API. If you will have question after this, I can ask again.